# ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit File Upload throws error in Scriptresource.axd

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, scriptresource.axd

I've got a AJAX Control Toolkit File Upload (Version 15.1.4)  that allows me to upload files to my ASP.Net Web Application. This worked great untill this week. Since yesterday the upload generates a JavaScript error as soon as I've selected a file.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'setText'
```

in the `ScriptResource.axd`:

```
fileInfoContainer.appendChild(fileInfoText);
fileInfoContainer.appendChild(fileStatusText);

$common.setText(deleteButton, Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Remove); <== here
$addHandlers(deleteButton, {
    'click': Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
        onRemoveItem(self);
    })
});
```

I can't remember that I've changed anything on this page (haven't touched in the last week) and another page in the Web Application that has a similar File Upload that works like a charm..

Has anybody got any idea why the ScriptResource throws this exception?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching I've finally found the problem. We use the obout richt text edit (https://www.obout.com/editor_new/) but this has a conflict with the FileUpload. Removing this control solved the problem.